# reading batch file parameters with equal sign and semi-colon

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to run a batch file on Windows 2008 R2 as follows:
Setup.bat 80,http,"Database=LbCore;Server=(localhost);Trusted_connection=yes","TestProduct","localhost"

I am printing the parameters in the batch file as follows:

```
ECHO *** Port=%~1,
ECHO *** Protocol=%~2,
ECHO *** Connection String=%~3, 
ECHO *** Service Name=%~4, 
ECHO *** Host Name=%~5
```

I am expecting the output as:

```
*** Port=80, 
*** Protocol=http, 
*** Connection String=Database=LbCore;Server=(localhost);Trusted_connection=yes, 
*** Service Name=TestProduct, 
*** Host Name=localhost
```

This is working fine on my machine. But surprisingly when I try to run it on some other Window 2008 R2 machine, it is printing:

```
*** Port=80, 
*** Protocol=http, 
*** Connection String=Database, 
*** Service Name=LbCore, 
*** Host Name=Server
```

It seems like on other machine, = and ; are treated as parameter delimiters.

Is there better approach to pass parameters with special characters as in above scenario?

Comment: `,; =` and <tab> are default delimiters in all Windows versions.

Answer (score 0):

Double quote the terms with special characters, or double quote them all.

```
call batch "80" "http" "Database=LbCore;Server=(localhost);Trusted_connection=yes" "etc"
```

EDIT: I note that you seem to be doing so but if it doesn't work on another machine then check the batch file and launcher on that machine.